# Can't make an animation counter to work in Safari and on mobile, although it works in Chrome on desktop just fine

Tags: html, css

This code makes a counter animate and count from 0 to 100 with all the number in between. In Safari and on mobile it goes static from 0 to 100 without icluding the animation.

Tried adding JS and/or jQuery to the code, with some luck with the counter to work. But other problems occurred like the counter didn't reset as intended.

[Codepen to the counter animation working in Chrome but not Safari](https://codepen.io/Astand/pen/bGmBPNd)

```
`<html>

<head>

<style>
@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

.div__counter--animate,
.div__counter--secondary {font: 700 6vw system-ui;}

.div__counter {
animation: counter 2.5s forwards linear ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation: counter 2.5s forwards alternate ease-in-out;
-moz-animation: counter 2.5s forwards alternate ease-in-out;
-ms-animation: counter 2.5s forwards alternate ease-in-out;
-o-animation: counter 2.5s forwards alternate ease-in-out;
  counter-reset: num var(--num);}

.div__counter::after {
content: counter(num);
animation: counter 2.5s forwards alternate ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation: counter 2.5s forwards alternate ease-in-out;
-moz-animation: counter 2.5s forwards alternate ease-in-out;
-ms-animation: counter 2.5s forwards alternate ease-in-out;
-o-animation: counter 2.5s forwards alternate ease-in-out;
  counter-reset: num var(--num);}

@-webkit-keyframes counter {
  from {
    --num: 0;
  }
  to {
    --num: 100;
  }
}

@keyframes counter {
  from {
    --num: 0;
  }
  to {
    --num: 100;
  }
}

.div__counter {font: 700 12vw system-ui !important;}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="div__counter"></div>

</body>

</html>`
```

Comment: If does not work in Firefox, on the desktop, Windows 11, either.

Comment: Any reason not to use Javascript for this?

Comment: `ease-in-out` is quite a weird choice for the animation timing function here. I would rather have expected to see `steps()` getting used.

Comment: The "easiest", albeit not prettiest, way to get this to work, would probably be to use `0% { --num: 0; } 1% { --num: 1; } ...` in your keyframes. (Could be generated dynamically via SASS/LESS, or JavaScript, if you don't want to type them all manually.)

Comment: Any beter way to do this? Need it to reset when the slide changes, and it does this way. My experience when adding JavaScript to this is that it comes with even more issues than it does with this. Any way to modify the way I've done it? This could be a great example of what I want to achieve: https://www.zoundindustries.com/about/